# Как узнать реальное разрешение экрана android

Tags: android

Имеется следующий код, он с его помощь я могу узнать физический размер экрана, но как мне узнать реальное разрешение в пикселях? Возможно вопрос задан некорректно, еще на до конца разобрался...

```
public static void getDensity(Activity activity, Context context){

    // Determine density
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int density = metrics.densityDpi;

    if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                "DENSITY_HIGH... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                "DENSITY_MEDIUM... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (density == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW) {
        Toast.makeText(context,
                "DENSITY_LOW... Density is " + String.valueOf(density),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Density is neither HIGH, MEDIUM OR LOW.  Density is "
                        + String.valueOf(density), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

public static void getPexelSize(Activity activity, Context context){
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int ht = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int wt = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

    Toast.makeText(context, "Screen size: " + wt +"/" + ht + " px", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: У вас же оно в последнем методе выводится... 0_о

Comment: @ЮрийСПб значит я все таки не так сформулировал вопрос, я недавно читал как это сделать,но не могу сейчас найти ту статью, там что то  перемножать надо...

Comment: Прежде чем начинать программировать, прочитайте/просмотрите хотя бы минимум уроков. Тогда вы не будете путаться в терминах, поймете ,что такое `px` и `dp`, и не будете их путать. А еще избавите нас от еще сотни таких вопросов.

Comment: @metalurgus я так и сделал, в уроках этой темы не касались , по крайней мере я не помню, поэтому я пришел сюда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос уже задавался на
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/get-screen-dimensions-in-pixels)

Вот решение

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Вне `Activity` можно получить размер экрана через `WINDOW_SERVICE`

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

Comment: я ж правильно понимаю, оно дает мне этот размер в зависимости от физического разрешения и плотности, правильно?

Comment: оно мне показывает те же размеры что и мой метод getPixelSize() , по-моему, это не то, что мне надо!

Comment: @KirillStoianov, ну а какие значения-то вам нужны? То, что вы получаете отличается от ТТХ устройства?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я сам не до конца понимаю что именно мне нужно:) я могу при использовании кастомных вьюх  отталкиваться от этих значений? что такое ТТХ?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб просто если я правильно понимаю,мне нужно количество пикселей которой учитывает плотность, ведь на двух экранах с одинаковым разрешение, но сразной плотностью  - будут иметь разное количество "не физических" пикселей

Comment: @KirillStoianov, Как из `px` получить `dp` смотрите [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9563438/3212712)

Comment: @KirillStoianov, а `ТТХ` это Тактико Технические Характеристики

Comment: понял. но мне не надо в dp,  мне в px надо, главное что  бы эти пиксели высчитывались  в зависимости от плотности( она же влияет на количество "виртуальных(не физических пикселей)) или я чего то не допонимаю?

Comment: Количество точек на дюйм что ли..

Comment: dp (dip) и есть пиксели высчитывающиеся в зависимости от плотности

Comment: @xkor похоже что на мой вопрос ответил еще вчера - ЮрийСПб . Я невнимательно прочитал.